# Safe sort with array key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

There is such a code. In which I sort the array by the name of the objects.

But the trouble is if for example instead of *first_name* or *last_name there* will be *nil, false*.

That is a mistake. **The error was: comparison of Array with Array failed.**

```
array.sort_by do |item|
    if item.expression
      [item.title, item.description]
    else
      [item.first_name, item.last_name]
    end
  end
```

How to safely sort for this case ?

```
[item.title || 0, item.description || 0]
```

I think it will not be professional to do so. Any good ideas?

Comment: `item.title || 0` won't work too. You can't compare integers to strings. At least you can do `item.title || ''` or a variation of it (`item.title.to_s`, etc.).

Comment: What behaviour do you expect if the `first_name` or `last_name` is `nil`? You've said "that is a mistake", but what do you mean by this? Are you saying it should be impossible for those fields to be `nil` in the first place? Or that they should be omitted from the results? Or that they should appear last in the sorted results? ....

Comment: @TomLord: nils i can understand, but `false`....

Comment: @TomLord
Data may be null.
And yes, it would be logical to exclude them from the main stream of sorting and throw them to the last in the sorted result.

Comment: Please edit your question to incorporate your comment above. Don't say "logical to...", just say what you want done with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I don't understand what you mean by "`first_name` and `last_name` may be `false`". That doesn't sound right not me. I'm going to assume that they're potentially `nil`, but not `false`.)

For a quick and simple workaround, you can coerce the `nil` values into `String`s, for example with:

```
array.sort_by do |item|
  if item.expression
    [String(item.title), String(item.description)]
  else
    [String(item.first_name), String(item.last_name)]
  end
end
```

This is *almost* equivalent to saying "sort alphabetically; `nil`s last".

It does not distinguish between a value being `""` vs a `nil`. If you want to make that aspect of the sorting stricter, you'll need to write [something more custom, using the `<=>` operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to do that. First, let's create some data.

```
Items = Struct.new(:expression, :title, :description, :first_name, :last_name)

values =
  [[false, 'x', 'x', 'Bob', nil],
   [true,  'Nine Lives', 'Cat story', 'x', 'x'],
   [false, 'x', 'x', 'Mary', 'Tuffet'],
   [false, 'x', 'x', false, 'Cocker'],
   [false, 'x', 'x', 'Lois', 'Lane'],
   [false, 'x', 'x', 'Bob', 'Newhart'],
   [true,  'Death Comes Calling', 'Who done it', 'x', 'x'],
   [false, 'x', 'x', 'Mary', 'Martin']]

array = values.map { |a| Items.new(*a) }
```

Note:

```
array.map do |item|
  [item.expression, item.title, item.description, item.first_name, item.last_name]
end == values
  #=> true
```

**Partition, sort and concatenate**

```
goodies, baddies = array.partition { |item|
  item.expression || (item.first_name && item.last_name) }

a = goodies.sort_by do |item| item.expression ? [item.title, item.description] :
      [item.first_name, item.last_name]
    end.concat(baddies)
```

```
a.map do |item|
  [item.expression, item.title, item.description, item.first_name, item.last_name]
end
  #=> [[false, "x", "x", "Bob", "Newhart"],
  #    [true, "Death Comes Calling", "Who done it", "x", "x"],
  #    [false, "x", "x", "Lois", "Lane"],
  #    [false, "x", "x", "Mary", "Martin"],
  #    [false, "x", "x", "Mary", "Tuffet"],
  #    [true, "Nine Lives", "Cat story", "x", "x"],
  #    [false, "x", "x", "Bob", nil],
  #    [false, "x", "x", false, "Cocker"]]
```

The last two elements are placed to the end. The preceding elements are ordered by the following:

```
["Bob", "Newhart"]
["Death Comes Calling", "Who done it"]
["Lois", "Lane"]
["Mary", "Martin"]
["Mary", "Tuffet"]
["Nine Lives", "Cat story"]
```

**Use [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sort)**

```
b = array.sort do |item1, item2|
  if    item1.expression==false && !(item1.first_name && item1.last_name)
    1
  elsif item2.expression==false && !(item2.first_name && item2.last_name)
    -1
  else
    (item1.expression ? [item1.title, item1.description] :
                        [item1.first_name, item1.last_name]) <=>
    (item2.expression ? [item2.title, item2.description] :
                        [item2.first_name, item2.last_name])
  end
end
```

```
b.first(6) == a.first(6)
  #=> true
```

The last two elements of `a` and `b` contain the same two elements but in different order. As the order of those elements was not specified that should not be a problem.